# PhpStorm fail to list grunt tasks

Tags: gruntjs, phpstorm

I've been using PhpStorm's grunt task runner for a while now. But after a update to PhpStorm to version 10 it stopped working. I'm getting and error;

```
Failed to list grunt tasks in /js/gruntfile.js: process finished with exit code 3 (a non-zero exit code means an error)
Running tasks: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt, _intellij_grunt_tasks_fetcher
Warning: Task "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt" not found. Use --force to continue

Aborted due to warnings.

Process finished with exit code 3
```

Even though it says "`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt` not found", file is actually there. Then I made the permission to 777 to see if it is permission issue. But it still giving me the same error.

My Grunt settings says,

[image]

But same Grunt file works perfectly on CLI mode, which is what I'm using at the moment. But I prefer to use PhpStorm grunt task runner as it'll be easier for me to manage all my dev work through one IDE.

I tried few things, and read few documents. Nothing about this particular scenario.

Comment: Your "Grunt Settings" screen asks for "Node Interpreter" -- why do you put path to grunt there?

Comment: An absolute bummer... Thank you man..  Why I didn't see that :o.  Anyway it's all good now, it had to be `/usr/local/bin/node` not `/usr/local/bin/grunt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on screenshot of your "Grunt Settings" dialog: you did put the path to your grunt in the field that asks for a path to **Node Interpreter**.

Providing path to the actual node executable should fix the issue for you.

---

> Even though it says "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt not found", file is actually there.

Nope.

If you read it again it actually says "**Task** xxx nod found". This suggests that most likely you either using wrong parameters (wrong values or wrong order) .. or parameters are right but actual program is wrong.

Comment: Yes, it's the interpreter path was wrong, It has to be `/usr/local/bin/node` instead. Thanks!!