# Failed to list Grunt tasks error in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, webstorm, babeljs

I am using JetBrains WebStorm 11.0.4 on Windows 7. I have a project with a Gruntfile.js file for which, when I attempt to have WebStorm "Reload Tasks", WebStorm fails with:

"**! Failed to list tasks**" in the Grunt pane.

The details of the error are:

```
Registering "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 11.0.4\plugins\JavaScriptLanguage\grunt_js\tasks" tasks.
Loading "grunt-tasks-fetcher.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\JetBrains\\WebStorm 11.0.4\\plugins\\JavaScriptLanguage\\grunt_js\\tasks"
>>   at <my_project>\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:395:17
>>   at Array.map (native)
>>   at OptionManager.resolvePresets (<my_project>\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:387:20)
>>   at OptionManager.mergePresets (<my_project>\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:370:10)
>>   at OptionManager.mergeOptions (<my_project>\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:330:14)
>>   at OptionManager.init (<my_project>\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:488:10)
>>   at compile (<my_project>\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:112:69)
>>   at loader (<my_project>\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:158:14)
>>   at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (<my_project>\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:168:7)
>>   at Module.load (<my_project>\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\register.js:45:36)
>>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
>>   at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
>>   at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
>>   at loadTask (<my_project>\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\task.js:316:10)
>>   at <my_project>\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\task.js:354:7
>>   at Array.forEach (native)
>>   at loadTasks (<my_project>\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\task.js:353:11)
>>   at task.loadTasks (<my_project>\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\task.js:365:5)
>>   at Array.forEach (native)
>>   at Task.task.init (<my_project>\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\task.js:457:45)
>>   at Object.grunt.tasks (<my_project>\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt.js:111:8)
>>   at Object.module.exports [as cli] (<my_project>\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\cli.js:27:9)
>>   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ME\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v5.6.0\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt:44:20)
>>   at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
>>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
>>   at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
>>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
>>   at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
>>   at startup (node.js:140:18)
>>   at node.js:1001:3

Running tasks: _intellij_grunt_tasks_fetcher
Warning: Task "_intellij_grunt_tasks_fetcher" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Googling with:

```
webstorm "failed to list tasks" gruntfile
```

...returns precisely zero results in English.

I am using `nvm` to manage multiple Node.js versions on my machine.  I have seen [other posts on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23927551/webstorm-does-not-recoginize-grunt) mentioning some dodgy interactions with nvm in scenarios like this, but as best I can tell, I don't think those anecdotes apply in my situation, as I'm using Windows.

I've scoured the web on this one for several hours over the course of weeks, and tried a variety of things -- nothing seems to help.

**UPDATE**

I awarded the bounty for this-- it was the closest I had gotten to a solution on my own-- but the *root* problem isn't really solved.  After some poking around in the Babel code itself, it looks like Babel is incorrectly looking for the `es2015` preset relative to the WebStorm directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 11.0.4\plugins\JavaScriptLanguage\grunt_js\tasks`

Not sure why, though.

If I move the `node_modules` directory from
`C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 11.0.4\plugins\JavaScriptLanguage\grunt_js\tasks`

into

`C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 11.0.4\plugins\JavaScriptLanguage\grunt_js`

... then it works.  **Anybody know why?**  (I mean, I understand that perhaps doing it that way satisfies Babel and WebStorm's desire to find the node_modules directory, but *WHY* is that?)

Comment: Is it WebStorm issue or Grunt issue? Is it reproducible in command line? Have you tried something like https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/178 ?

Comment: may be the duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329807/phpstorm-fail-to-list-grunt-tasks

Comment: Try add babelrc: false inside the babel options:

Answer (score 3):

`Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015"` is a `babel-cli` error. Some where it is specifying to load the npm module `babel-preset-es2015`, do you have the file `.babelrc` in your project directory with presets set?

You could try installing `babel-preset-es2015` and see if error still appears.

Answer (score 0):

Try with node v4.5.0 or higher and the latest version of npm, could you try this?

- remove node_modules of project
- npm install -g npm
- Insure that `babel-preset-es2015` and `babel-preset-stage-2` installed by npm
- babel configuration in `.babelrc` file

  `"babel": {
      "presets": [
        "es2015",
        ....
      ]
    },`
- run WebStorm "Reload Tasks"

May be this should be work.